# Qt MVC - Get filename when user clicks?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, model, qlist, qfilesystemmodel

Okay, I have the following code:

```
 QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
 model->setRootPath(QDir::currentPath());
 model->setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot |
                  QDir::Readable | QDir::Writable | QDir::CaseSensitive );

 ui->fileList->setModel(model);
 ui->fileList->setRootIndex(model->index(QDir::currentPath()));
```

How can I find out which item (specifically, its corresponding filename) has been selected? I want the user to select a file using the mouse, such that the selected filename can be passed to a method I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using QTreeWidget? It has an [abstract item model](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreeview.html). You need to get the [model index](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreewidget.html#indexFromItem) from the [selected item](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreewidget.html#itemClicked)

Comment: Same principle applies -- convert the list/tree/whatever items into the abstract model index and then go back into the abstract model which is attached to the widget.

Comment: Cheers, the annswer was to do model->fileName(ui->fileList->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().first())